# Failed to export .tif file from SAGA GIS

Tags: geotiff-tiff, saga, output

I calculated Topographic wetness Index (TWI) and Topographic Position index (TPI) for the whole Austria but failed to export the result. The following is the process to export the result:

(1) The result of the calculation is normal

[image]

(2) Export the result by clicking right mouse button on the layer and choose "save as" to export the result as .tif file.

[image]

(3) Failed without any error messages or instruments about reasons lead to the failed export.

[image]

(4) In the file I save the result shows both TWI and TPI, but with the exact same size, 7211425 KB.

[image]

Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: My only thought would be to check free disk space

Comment: I did, there are still more than 1 TB